# Restore Solaris 11 on Linux Redhat 7.3 virtual machine

Tags: solaris

Is it possible to export the OS image of Solaris 11 and use in Linux Redhat 7.3 virtual machine?

Comment: My first answer would be 'No', apart from that please provide more details like what VM provider or hypervisor are you using and why do you want to do this?

Comment: My base OS is Linux Redhat 7.3, by using virt-manager I need to restore one Solaris 11 Os and one Linux 7.3 Os for some specific products purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Solaris 11 will run fine under Xen.  KVM presents some problems, it'll run but networking doesn't work which means it probably doesn't do what you need.